# How to migrate on Object from one JVM to other JVM

Tags: java, tomcat, failover

can anyone help me in implementing  how to migrate the objects from one JVM to other if my application (running on two machines ) is crashed and the other one can take hold from it.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html ?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is not available in JVM out of the box, but some thirdparty solutions exist.  Look at [terracotta](http://terracotta.org/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it work if you make your object serializable and send it over a stream to a server for example?